# MS project 2010 save gannt chart as pdf in to single page

Tags: pdf, ms-project

I created a gannt chart using MS Project 2010 and I wanted it to be saved as a PDF file. But it gives me the chart as 4 parts in 4 pages which makes it unreadable. There are no flexible options in save as pdf. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that on MS-Project it self. I simply used a printer driver software ("pdf995" >> http://www.pdf995.com/) and it allowed me to do adjustments to save the pdf by giving the options it gives when printing the document. 
It saved my whole effort.

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces of software, either Onepager Pro or Milestone Professional, that will allow you to do this (a new, consolidated Gantt chart;) it's not easy to do in Project by itself.